# Angular.js UI router - how can a query param's value contain other query param key as part of its value?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

With Angular.JS UI router, what I'm trying to do is: the value of one of the query params, contains the other query param keys in it as part of its value.
For example with url  definition of:

```
url: "/myApp/u1/u2?{qp1}&{qp2}&{qp3}&{qp4}"
```

the url user hits as:

```
http:/myApp/u1/u2?qp1=val1&qp2=val2&qp3=qp1%3Dval10%26qp2%3Dval20&qp4=val4
```

the `qp3` is not parsed correctly, instead some of its value contents which contain `qp1` and `qp2` strings, it get parsed into values of `qp1` and `qp2`, instead.

How can I achieve this?

I also tried to use regex for query params, but it does not get routed.The below don't work

```
url:  "/myApp/u1/u2?{qp1}&{qp2:[0-9]{1,3}}"
```

also can not use 'bool' that is defined in ui router. The below don't work

```
url:  "/myApp/u1/u2?{qp1}&{qp2}&{qp3:bool}"
```

Is this a limitation on query params support in angularjs ui router

Comment: what are you passing to the params in href's? And how are you creating the url's? Appears the values aren't very clean

Comment: the value of qp3 in above example is encoded. Hence qp1%3Dval10%26qp2%3Dval20   is encoded value for qp1=val10&qp2=val20

Comment: can't you just decode it?

Comment: the issue is not decoding the value of qp3 in above example. Turns out when value of a query param contains any other query params defined in 'url' value passed to ui router, it parses them to be repeated query parameters. Hence to get around it, I was passing encoded value for qp3 in above example.

Comment: now that makes sense ... sure looks that way too

Comment: and I was getting surprised how the value of qp3 was getting decoded. I had thought ui router was doing that. Turns out in our code, we were decoding whole query string just before it was directed to ui router.

Comment: Also I believe, with ui router, the regex support that is described for url parameters in docs is NOT there for query parameters ( I was assuming it would be)